# how to locate link at center

Tags: html

what i am trying is to  locate  links  at center,namely suppose we have following code

```
<html  >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="blue">

<a href="indexE.html"><img src ='english.gif' style="float:right"  width="88" height="88"> </a>
<a href="indexR.html"><img src ='russian.gif' alt="Russian flag" style="float:right"  width="88" height="88"/>
<a href="index.html"> <img src="georgian.jpg"  style="float:right" width="88" height="88"/>
<a href="index.html">მთავარი </a>

</body>
</html>
```

here (მთავარი)(mtavari) means main,just i am doing site into english,georgian,and russian language,what i want it to locate main(მთავარი)at center,could you help me?also how to enlarge text?

EDITED:

```
<html  >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<style>
#links {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:1050px; 
     font-size:70px

}
</style>
<body bgcolor="blue" >
<a href="indexE.html"><img src ='english.gif' style="float:right"  width="88" height="88"> </a>
<a href="indexR.html"><img src ='russian.gif' alt="Russian flag" style="float:right"  width="88" height="88"/>
<a href="index.html"> <img src="georgian.jpg"  style="float:right" width="88" height="88"/>
<div id="links">

<a href="index.html">მთავარი </a>
</div>
<div id="links">
<a href="ბაკურიანი.html">ბაკურიანი </a>
</div>
<div id="links">
<a href="გუდაური.html">გუდაური </a>
</div>
<div id="links">
<a href="ზღვა.html">ზღვა </a>
</div>
<div id="links">
<a href="კახეთი.html">კახეთი </a>
</div>
<div id="links">
<a href="სვანეთი.html">სვანეთი </a>
</div>
<div id="links">
<a href="ვარძია.html">ვარძია </a>
</div>
<a href="ქართლი.html">ქართლი </a>
</div>
<div id="links">
<a href="ძველი_თბილისი.html">ძველი_თბილისი </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "locate"? EDIT: Do you mean, fetch the element with that string so that you could change the string depending on the language?

Comment: i want to  do like this http://math.stackexchange.com/   here  questions,tags and etc are located as  i like to  do

Comment: I don't think you should wrap it in an anchor tag (<a>) then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about centring the links in the centre of the page? Then you cold use css:
Wrap the  tags in a div and then centre the div. In order for the div to centre, you need to assign it a width. As an example, I chose 600px. You're also missing a couple closing a tags.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<style>
#links {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;   
}

#test { 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 400px; 
    clear: both; 
    display: block;
}
#test a {
    float: right;
}

</style>

<body bgcolor="blue">

<div id="links">
    <a href="indexE.html"><img src ='english.gif' style="float:right"  width="88" height="88"> </a>
    <a href="indexR.html"><img src ='russian.gif' alt="Russian flag" style="float:right"  width="88" height="88"/></a>
    <a href="index.html"> <img src="georgian.jpg"  style="float:right" width="88" height="88"/></a>
</div>

<div id="test">
    <a href="index.html">test1</a>
    <a href="index.html">test2</a>
    <a href="index.html">test3</a>
    <a href="index.html">test4</a>
    <a href="index.html">test5</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To enlarge text in the links, just add to the #links style--> font-size:18px, etc.

Comment: thanks very much,just one question  მთავარი is located on top part,how can i locate it in middle one?

Comment: Do you mean you want it in the middle of the flags? The flags all have float:right applied to them, and it does not. You could add float:right to მთავარი, but you would also need to change its order in your html: the first a tag will appear to the far right, the second to its left, and so on.

Comment: no what i meant is that ,მთავარი is located on top of page,i want  to move it i middle of page so that,after i add additional tags,these tags should be alongside to each other like this http://math.stackexchange.com/ here questions,tags,etc are located after each other

Comment: So do you want the მთავარი to appear under the row of flags? Then you can keep it outside the div containing the flags, with a style to centre it so the html would look like: <div id="links">
<a href="indexE.html"><img src ='english.gif' style="float:right"  width="88" height="88"> </a>
<a href="indexR.html"><img src ='russian.gif' alt="Russian flag" style="float:right"  width="88" height="88"/></a>
<a href="index.html"> <img src="georgian.jpg"  style="float:right" width="88" height="88"/></a>
</div>
<a href="index.html" id="მთავარი">მთავარი </a>

Comment: And you would add the style: #მთავარი { margin: 0 auto; width: 100px; clear: both; display: block;}

Comment: sorry but my aim is  different,i dont need flags at this moment,what i need is that i have following flags მთავარი,ბაკურიანი,სვანეთი,კახეთი and so one,but they are located not alongside each other,but below each other please see following  code,i will update and for working,just remove flags picture and see how they are located,i need in middle  part of page ,they should be located like 1  2  3 4

Comment: Ok, if you want them vertically, I have reposted code that should do the trick. One thing to note - be careful of your tag id's - you can't use an id more than once.

Comment: test1 test2  .. are located verticaly,i need horizontal  ,like straight line

Answer (score 1):

Just put text-align: center to the containing element, the body in this case.

Second, you forgot some closing anchor-tags (</a>).
Lastly, you should change styles to CSS in stead of inline.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: blue;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .flag {
                float: right;
                height: 88px;
                width: 88px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="indexE.html"><img class="flag" src='english.gif'></a>
        <a href="indexR.html"><img class="flag" src='russian.gif' alt="Russian flag"/></a>
        <a href="index.html" ><img class="flag" src='georgian.jpg'/></a>
        <a href="index.html">მთავარი </a>
    </body>
</html>
```